# Why react rerender all elements in functional component on input change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand how to stop rerendering elements in functional component (or maybe I don't need to ?)

I am using single useState for all inputs and share the same onChange handler.

I have huge amounts of input fields in forms (100+) and whenever I type in any of them in dev tools profiler I see they all rerender, assuming this is because on each renders my onChange handler is "recreated" and all input elements rerender too.
If I try to wrap it in useCallback nothing changes, but if I wrap my input element in Rect.memo component then it doesn't rerender.

```
    const MyInput = props => {
  return <input {...props} />;
};

const MyInputMemo = React.memo(props => {
  return <input {...props} />;
});

function App() {
  React.useDebugValue("test");

  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    name1: "test 1",
    name2: "test 2",
    name3: "test 3"
  });
  const [singleInput, setSingleInput] = useState("single input handler");

  const onHandleInputChange = e => {
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onHandleInputChangeSingle = useCallback(e => {
    setSingleInput(e.target.value);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ padding: "30px" }}>
      <div>
        <h1>Test form</h1>
      </div>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>shared onChange</label>
          <MyInput
            name="name1"
            value={formValues.name1}
            onChange={onHandleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>shared onChange</label>
          <MyInput
            name="name2"
            value={formValues.name2}
            onChange={onHandleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>shared onChange (memo)</label>
          <MyInputMemo
            name="name3"
            value={formValues.name3}
            onChange={onHandleInputChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>self onChanged</label>
          <input
            name="name4"
            value={singleInput}
            onChange={onHandleInputChangeSingle}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <pre>shared state:{JSON.stringify(formValues, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
        <div>
          <pre>single state: {JSON.stringify(singleInput, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: picture]

here is simplified [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-render-fields-9coi0) example

Am I profiling something wrong or is this normal behavior, should I be concerned about performance and if so how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default React recalculates all the variables inside of functional component.

You have to use `useCallback` and `useMemo` to memoize variables and recalculate them only if their dependencies change.

So you have to wrap `onHandleInputChange` in `useCallback` (otherwise you always recreate it and this prop updates for inputs every render).

Additionally, you have to wrap your parent and children functional components in `React.memo`. It's equivalent of `PureComponent` for classes.

Comment: i did wrap 
  const onHandleInputChangeSingle = useCallback(e => {
    setSingleInput(e.target.value);
  }, []); it and it still rerenders on each key press on each field .. in sandbox there are 4 input fields one wrapped with useCallback, other with memo, third one single callback

Comment: i did :) const MyInputMemo = React.memo(props => {
  return <input {...props} />;
});
and it still rerenders

Comment: Hmm, I'll try to check this

Comment: I wrapped `App`, `MyInput` in `React.memo`, added useCallback for `onHandleInputChange` and it works good for me now

Comment: @MatijaGluhak try this https://codesandbox.io/s/test-render-fields-pw97h
Open the console and input something

Comment: your onHandleInputChange missing formValues as dependecies on useCallback, it doesn't work if you don't put it and when you do, then it is every time new function I think. try typing on another input elements it reset old ones that shares nadler